# XAML ResourceDictionary same-assembly reference

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm developing a WPF control library, and I need to reference a resource dictionary **defined in the same assembly**.

I managed to get it working with a *separate-assembly* reference.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary
             Source="pack://application:,,,/MyLocalAssembly;component/Foo.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

While with a *same-assembly* reference it doesn't work, and raises an exception ("Cannot locate resource 'Foo.xaml'.") at load time. **Note that in the designer everything works fine, no matter which method I use**.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary
             Source="pack://application:,,,/Foo.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use absolute path for the resource dictionary.  Simply use relative path reference.

For example,

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary
             Source="folder/Foo.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. I need to investigate Pack URI's a little more.